# WP7: How to effectively load 100+ small pictures in one view

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I am trying to make a long `ListBox` with each `ListBoxItem` being a tile with a small 100x100 logo inside it. Right now it's very slow - using more than 5-6 seconds just to become responsive. Since the images are downloaded from the web async (and each one is stored inside each own model instance), I don't know how to check when they have all downloaded either (i.e. no progress indicator to cover the delay).

Do you have any idea as to how I can do this in the most effective way possible?

XAML:

```
                 <ListBox>
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListBox.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ListBox.Template>

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ListBoxItem>
                                    <Grid Name="ChannelTile" Tap="ChannelTile_Tap">
                                        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource LightGrayColor}" />
                                        <Image Style="{StaticResource Tiles_Image}" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ListBoxItem>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reference the images in binding (Source={Binding Image}) by URL, try using the LowProfileImageLoader from PhonePerformance (http://nuget.org/packages/PhonePerformance)

Comment: I am not actually - I have made quite an elaborate getter for the image which actually returns the Image through the Image.Source async call

Comment: Try binding to URLs with the LowProfileImageLoader. It is a smart class that does async downloading of images

Comment: Igor, thank you thank you thank you - I have been trying every single thing to make this work, and this framework worked perfectly after some trial and error.